# PHP pass additional data to a callback

Tags: php, string, oop, callback

```
class A {

    protected function b($string, $data) {
        return preg_replace_callback('/pattern/', [$this, 'c'], $string);
    }

    protected function c($match) {
        return $data[$match[1]];
    }

}
```

I want to be able to access `$data` from function `c`.

Things I **DO NOT** want to do:

- define an anonymous function inside `b`, because `b` will get called fairly frequently and I don't want to define a new function every time.
- bind `$data` to the instance of `A`, because then it will remain in memory until the instance is destroyed. I want to just pass the data and let it be collected after the replace has finished.

Do I have any other options?

Comment: Maybe instead of an anonymous function just call `$this->c($data);` in `b`? Maybe I misunderstood your intention.

Comment: @Kapparina `c` is getting called by `preg_replace_callback`, not me

Comment: You should go for an anonymous function. PHP is smart enough to cache the bytecode and not redefine the function on each call. If you think it could cause a performance issue, you should consider benchmarking the function and you'll find that your optimization probably doesn't change anything.

Comment: @this.lau_ that's very interesting, so php caches every single anonymous function ever defined (in the script) and if I try to define the absolutely same function, somewhere else entirely independent of the first declaration, php will already have it cached?

Comment: Scenario seems a bit convoluted. But couldn't assign $data to an instance variable of `A`, and set it before calling the function and unset it immediately afterwards, if you want that memory marked as available for the GC?

Comment: @yivi why would you say that is convoluted? If I did that I would need to assign the output of `preg_replace` to a variable, that's an operation I'd like to avoid doing if possible.

Comment: You shouldn't try to force something, that (according to your description) looks like meant for functional programming, inside the oop paradigm. Either there is no point in wrapping this in a class **OR** your question has left out the context.

Comment: With your restrictions you've set what you're asking for is impossible. You can't share a variable that's in the scope of one function in the scope of another function without having to bind it at a place which is commonly accessible.

Comment: for what u need access to $data ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i highly recommend using an anonymous function for this. I know you dont want to, but it is the lest dirty way to do what you want.

I did sonse tests. A callback as in your Question and a version with an anonymous functoin.

Test I made: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/01t6-rqjh

**Results** (values are seconds)

```
| cycles  | callable         | anonymous function |
|---------|------------------|--------------------|
| 1000    | 0.00196886062622 | 0.00189614295959   |
| 100000  | 0.187341928482   | 0.205796957016     |
| 1000000 | 1.88189315796    | 1.87302780151      |
```

As you can see, there is not much of a difference.

Anyway, here is my solution for you:

```
class A {
    protected function b($string, $data) {
        return preg_replace_callback('/pattern/', function($match) use ($data) {return $data[$match[1]];}, $string);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that you don't want

> ...to define an anonymous function inside b, because b will get called
>   fairly frequently and I don't want to define a new function every
>   time.

But I still provide you a code version which does exactly what you... don't want. Or it... doesn't? ;-)

Beside this one, I think that there could also be another solution: recursively calling your `b` method as the callback. I didn't try to implement it yet. But I'll certainly do it.

I felt, of course, free to change your absolutely minimal namings as I wished. Don't take it personal! :-)

I'm kidding. Good luck.

```
<?php

class Replacement {

    /**
     * Handler for the preg-replace matches.
     * 
     * @var Closure
     */
    private $handler;

    /**
     * 
     * @param mixed $subject The string or an array with strings to search and replace.
     * @param mixed $pattern The pattern to search for.
     * @param array $replacements Replacements list.
     * @param integer $matchPosition [optional] Match-position for which a replacement takes place.
     * @param integer $recreate [optional] If TRUE, recreate handler.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function start($subject, $pattern, $replacements, $matchPosition = 1, $recreate = FALSE) {
        $this->createHandler($replacements, $matchPosition, $recreate);
        return preg_replace_callback($pattern, $this->handle(), $subject);
    }

    /**
     * Create a handler for the preg-replace matches.
     * A replacements list is passed.
     * 
     * Creation takes place only once in the lifecycle
     * of the instance of this class.
     * 
     * @param array $replacements Replacements list.
     * @param integer $matchPosition [optional] Match-position for which a replacement takes place.
     * @param integer $recreate [optional] If TRUE, recreate handler.
     * @return $this
     */
    public function createHandler($replacements, $matchPosition = 1, $recreate = FALSE) {
        if (!isset($this->handler) || $recreate) {
            $this->handler = function($matches) use ($replacements, $matchPosition) {
                return $replacements[$matches[$matchPosition]];
            };
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Handle preg-replace matches.
     * 
     * @return Closure
     */
    public function handle() {
        return $this->handler;
    }

}

// Subject string.
$subject = 'Next april fools day is 04/01/2018 and the last Christmas was 12/24/2017.';

// Pattern to search for: mm/dd or yyyy.
$pattern = "|(\d{2}/\d{2}/)(\d{4})|";

// Create test object
$replacement = new Replacement();


// Display results.
echo '<pre><b>BEFORE:</b> "' . print_r($subject, true) . '"</pre>' . PHP_EOL;

//*******************************************
// TEST 1: Closure creation
//*******************************************

// Replacement data.
$replacements = [
    '04/01/' => 'the same as each year',
    '12/24/' => 'in december',
];

// Start replacement process.
$output = $replacement->start($subject, $pattern, $replacements);

// Display results.
echo '<pre><b>AFTER (test 1):</b> "' . print_r($output, true) . '"</pre>' . PHP_EOL;

//*******************************************
// TEST 2: Closure RE-creation
//*******************************************

$replacements2 = [
    '04/01/' => 'test1',
    '12/24/' => 'test2',
];

// Start replacement process.
$output2 = $replacement->start($subject, $pattern, $replacements2, 1, TRUE);

// Display results.
echo '<pre><b>AFTER (test 2):</b> "' . print_r($output2, true) . '"</pre>' . PHP_EOL;
```

### EDIT 1:

Oh, just forgot: The subject string and the pattern in my example are taken from the PHP docs. I changed the subject string a little bit, in order to give it a better sense. Anyway, the PHP guys can explain the patterns better then me (I'm not an expert in regex's):

- [Example #2 preg_replace_callback() example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

And for the recursive solution see

- [Example #3 preg_replace_callback() using recursive structure to
  handle encapsulated BB code](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

### EDIT 2 (20.06.'17):

I changed the code: closure recreated on-demand by reading the `$recreate` bool value now. You can decide if the recreation takes place before starting replacement, by checking if the array values have changed since their initial form.

Comment: Very interesting, but how are `$replacements` in `createHandler` not remaining as the initial value passed? I'm going to look into that!

Comment: Replacements are kept and you can not use this function twice, [see here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6025cf6281fb4c2f4f1b13d2bdf2d60f8ff76986).

Comment: @php_nub_qq Hi, so... what do you mean?

Comment: @php_nub_qq You mean replacements & mposition are read on creation and can't be changed through object lifecycle?

Comment: @php_nub_qq I changed the code correspondingly to fit the new requirements.

Comment: @php_nub_qq You'll have the impression, that the new form is not flexible. Well, it is. Because how you handle the replacement, e.g how/when you create your object, or change the replacements array, or etc, is up to you. Also read the notes in EDIT 2.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a static field on the class to avoid memory usage or use a non-static field and just clear it before returning. Something like this:

```
class A { 

    protected static $_data;

    protected function b($string, $data) {
        self::$_data = $data;
        $return = preg_replace_callback('/pattern/', [self, 'c'], $string);
        unset(self::$_data);
        return $return;
    }

    protected function c($match) {
        return array_shift(self::$_data);
    }

}
```

Comment: How is that any different (or better) than binding `$data` to the instance?

Comment: Well it is binding $data to the instance but if you have a static property it doesn't affect server memory as much since only one instance of $data is used, if you unset it afterwards it will only be populated while the function is running

Answer (score 0):

I would create a separate class with `$data` property, so you can set it on an object:

```
interface IReplacer
{
    public function handler(array $matches);
}

class DataReplacer implements IReplacer
{
    private $data;

    public function __construct(array $data = null)
    {
        if (!is_null($data)) {
            $this->data = $data;
        }
    }

    public function setData(array $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;

        return $this;
    }

    public function clearData()
    {
        $this->data = null;

        return $this;
    }

    public function handler(array $matches)
    {
        if (!isset($this->data[$matches[0]])) {
            // Do what ever is more plausable here.
            // Throw an exception or provide default value.
            return 'default value';
        }

        return $this->data[$matches[0]];
    }
}
```

Then you will inject an object of this class as a dependency into your `A` class:

```
class A
{
    private $replacer;

    public function __construct(IReplacer $replacer)
    {
        $this->replacer = $replacer;
    }

    public function b($string, array $data)
    {
        $result = preg_replace_callback(
            '/pattern/',
            [$this->replacer->setData($data), 'handler'],
            $string
        );

        // Clear data so it is not hanging around in the memory.
        $this->replacer->clearData();

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Having this you can use it like (I have made method `b` public for the sake of testing simplicity):

```
$a = new A(new DataReplacer);

$string = 'This is example with pattern';

var_dump($a->b($string, ['pattern' => 'foo']));
var_dump($a->b($string, ['pattern' => 'bar']));
var_dump($a->b($string, []));
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d34af13dda5d67193f23d904ee2a685970b39b2f).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 strategies you can consider to access the data variable:

1. Hide its contents in your regex. Example:

   ```
   $string = "Goodbye cruel world!";
   $replacements = [ "Goodbye" => "Hello", "cruel" => "nice" ];
   //Build your regex with named capturing groups e.g. 
   $result = preg_replace_callback("/(?P<Hello>Goodbye)|(?P<nice>cruel)/" , function ($match) {
           $filtered = array_filter($match,function ($v,$k) { return $v != null && !is_numeric($k); }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
           return array_keys($filtered)[0];
   }, $string);
   ```
2. If all else fails there's always the backtrace:

   ```
   protected function b($string, $data) {
       return preg_replace_callback('/pattern/', [$this, 'c'], $string);
   }

   protected function c($match) {
       //Second argument of the function that is 3rd on the call stack
       // 0 is this function 1 is the preg_replace_callback function so 2 is b
       $data = debug_backtrace()[2]["args"][2]; 
   return $data[$match[1]];
   }
   ```

Notes: There's very strict limitations in what names the capturing groups can have so it's probably not a viable choice many times. However I don't think the backtrace will offer any sort of improvement over binding the function though.

I'd suggest you do the simple:

```
protected function b($string, $data) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/pattern/', function ($match) use ($data) {
       return $data[$match[1]];
    }, $string);
}
```

which is just embedding the function. PHP optimizations will prevent the `$data` array from being copied unless it's actually modified.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
class A {

    private $data;

    protected function b($string, $data) {
        $this->data = $data;
        return preg_replace_callback('/pattern/', [$this, 'c'], $string);
    }

    protected function c($match) {
        return $this->data[$match[1]];
    }

}
```